# Reading facebook feed posts

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

i use the following code to read my facebook feed:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$appId = "{my app id}";
$appSecret = "{my app secret}";

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $appId,
  'app_secret' => $appSecret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.1'
]);


$accessToken = {my access token};

$postData = "";
try {
    $userPosts = $fb->get("/{mypage}/feed", $accessToken);
    $postBody = $userPosts->getDecodedBody();
    $postData = $postBody["data"];
} catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // display error message
    exit();
} catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // display error message
    exit();
}

print_r($postData);
?>
```

This works fine but the result-array does only contain Text without linebreaks and Images (which are in the original posts).
Also linked You-Tube Pages are not contained.

Is there a possibility to get ALL content of the posts?

Also i want to create a like button foreach post.

Bet regards and thanx for your help

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

sorry, got the answer already.

changing

```
$userPosts = $fb->get("/{mypage}/feed", $accessToken);
```

to

```
$userPosts = $fb->get("/{mypage}/feed?fields=created_time,message,attachments", $accessToken);
```

solved my problem.